# Concurrent collection of listeners

Tags: java, concurrency

I am dealing with some problem. I found a solution that works, but I'm still confused and think that there is a better one.

I have model class with collection of listeners of type let's say IListener. Other classes are allowed to add or remove listener via public methods.

My model class uses 2 threads to update some data and after this process is finished, listeners are notified about model changes.

So code goes like this

```
void updateThread1() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        updateLogic();
        List<IListener> listenersCopy = new ArrayList<>(listeners);
        for (IListener listener : listenersCopy) {
             listener.dataUpdated();
        }
    }

void updateThread2() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        updateLogic2();
        List<IListener> listenersCopy = new ArrayList<>(listeners);
        for (IListener listener : listenersCopy) {
             listener.dataUpdated();
        }
    }
```

And here is my problem: as listeners can be added or removed by different threads then updateThread1 and updateThread2 so there is a pretty good chance to get ConcurrentModificationException.

I can't tell whether creating copy of array is atomic (i.e. ArrayList#addAll() uses some native array copy mechanizm).

I tried to used CopyOnWriteArrayList, which works fine. Second approach was to use concurrent hash set (from Collections#newSetFromMap()) that was backed by ConcurrentHashMap.

This works for me, but I'd like to know whether there are some design approaches to make it work.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Given that you already synchronize these methods on the same lock, why don't you also synchronize the methods allowing to add/remove listeners? What state is the synchonized block proptecting, if not the list of listeners? That said, if you choose not to use synchronization, a CopyOnWriteArrayList seems like a good choice since you'll probably have few listeners, and add/remove them very rarely.

Comment: yeah, but then add / remove methods that are called from EDT may be blocked for a while. I tried to avoid it.

Comment: @user464592 `that are called from EDT may be`  - all methods implemented in AWT/Swing APIs must be called on EDT